# Explode json string by take column values as column names

Tags: json, pyspark

I'm trying to explode a json string in pyspark and bring one column's value as the column name. In my data frame I have the json string like,

```
{"AA02": {"param": "F7VH", "value": "QP3"}}
{"AA01": {"param": "F7VH", "value": "CKA"}}
```

[image]

I need to generate a json file from this column like,

```
{
    "AA02": {
        "param": "F7VH",
        "value": "QP3"
    },
    "AA01": {
        "param": "F7VH",
        "value": "CKA"
    }
}
```

I tried many ways like pivoting, to_json using a schema. But nothing helped to solve me the problem. I'm thinking of a way to take out the entire columns values as a json and create a new dataframe like,

```
df_new = df.select(col("to_json"), json_tuple(col("to_json"), "param", "value")).toDF("id", "param","value")
```

This returns,

[image]

Any way to do this using PySpark only or should I use vanilla python for this somehow?

Comment: What is the data type of the `to_json` column?

Comment: it's a string value

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract values from the nested JSON, so you need to get the nested JSON before applying `json_tuple`.

```
df = (df.withColumn('col', F.from_json('col', 'map<string, map<string, string>>'))
      .withColumn('col', F.col('col').getItem(F.map_keys('col').getItem(0)))
      .select('id', F.json_tuple(F.to_json('col'), 'param', 'value'))
      .toDF('id', 'param', 'value'))
```